# How do pallet and consensus model/algorithm/infrastructure work together?

Tags: transactions, consensus

Hi guys I am new to blockchain and susbtrate, so these questions would be stupid to you...But I really need some help here...

- How does substrate ensure anything has been done inside the pallet will be synced on (accepted by) the chain (when/where does the consensus model/module/infra kick in)?
- And what will happen if the **thing** (should be synced) is rejected by the chain ?
- Where can I find the source code referring to this feature/ answering to these questions ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read transaction lifecycle, it will help you on your first question and second question, Source code refer to parity/substrate repo

Comment: Okay! Thanks a lot Mrisho!